# Calendar Activity Viewer

Tags: java, android, ui

Интересует семпл/материалы как написать свой кастомный вьювер. 
Есть пример как должен выглядеть вьювер : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никогда не писал кастомные адаптеры/юаи на andorid sdk.

Comment: что такое *вьювер*?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: @metalurgus я могу сказать свою интерпретацию данного определения - область экрана/элемент который каким либо путем ( статически/динамически) взаимодействует с юзрверем

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `View`(*вью*)?

Comment: @metalurgus именно

Comment: тогда откорректируйте вопрос